# How to remove error:has magic number 'PK-' Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated?

Tags: r, macos, rda

R 4.0.3 GUI 1.73 Catalina build (7892)  for mac

```
Error in load("/Users/***/Desktop/R2019.r d a") : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘R2019. r d a’ has magic number 'PK-'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

Comment: `"R2019.r d a"` you have spaces in your file extension?

Comment: there is no spaces ， R2019.rda